# Filter out groups with NaN values for one column in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
  city district  year  price
0   bj       cy  2018    NaN
1   bj       cy  2019    6.0
2   sh       hp  2018    4.0
3   sh       hp  2019    3.0
4   bj       hd  2018    7.0
5   bj       hd  2019    NaN
```

How could I groupby `city` and `district`, and filter rows if `price` is `NaN`? Thank you.

The output I needed is like this:

```
  city district  year  price
0   bj       cy  2018    NaN
1   bj       cy  2019    6.0
2   bj       hd  2018    7.0
3   bj       hd  2019    NaN
```

I have tried with `df.groupby(['city', 'district']).filter(lambda df: df[df['price'].isnull()])`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: your filter could work with this : ```df.groupby(['city','district']).filter(lambda x: x.price.isna().any())```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with test if at least one `NaN`, it means one `True` per group:

```
mask = (df.assign(test = df['price'].isnull())
          .groupby(['city', 'district'])['test']
          .transform('any'))
df = df[mask]

print (df)
  city district  year  price
0   bj       cy  2018    NaN
1   bj       cy  2019    6.0
4   bj       hd  2018    7.0
5   bj       hd  2019    NaN
```

If performance is not important or small DataFrame is possible use [`DataFrameGroupBy.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['city','district']).filter(lambda x: x['price'].isnull().any())
```

Comment: and how to filter groupby rows without `NaN`s?

Comment: @ahbon - Simpliest is invert mask `df1= df[~mask]`

Comment: Sorry, one more question, if I need to exclude groups whose `year` is `2019` and `price` is `NaN`?

Comment: @ahbon - Do you think changed `df.assign(test = df['price'].isnull())` to `df.assign(test = df['price'].isnull() & df['year'].eq(2019))` ?

Comment: Is it possible to do it with your second solution?

Comment: @ahbon - yop, `lambda x: x['price'].isnull().any() and df['year'].eq(2019).any()` ? There is `and` because scalars

Comment: It raises an error: `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'`.

Comment: @ahbon - One idea, can you test `df = df.groupby(['city','district']).filter(lambda x: (x['price'].isnull() & x['year']).any())` ?

Comment: No missing values for that column, I have checked. In fact, in real data, it's a date column but I converted them to string, so I `df['price'].isnull() & df['date'].str.contains('2019-04-01')`, and `df['price'].isnull() & df['date'].isin(['2019-04-01'])`, both doesn't works.

Comment: I put another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61385609/filter-grouped-rows-based-on-multiple-conditions-in-pandas