# Filter grouped rows based on multiple conditions in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
  city district        date  price
0   bj       cy  2019-03-01    NaN
1   bj       cy  2019-04-01    6.0
2   sh       hp  2019-03-01    4.0
3   sh       hp  2019-04-01    3.0
4   bj       hd  2019-03-01    7.0
5   bj       hd  2019-04-01    NaN
```

I need to filter grouped rows of `city` and `district` when both of the following conditions were met: `date` is `2019-04-01` and `price` is `NaN`.

I have tested with the following code:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date.astype(str)
df.groupby(['city','district']).filter(lambda x: (x['price'].isnull() & x['date'].isin(['2019-04-01'])).any())
```

Out:

```
  city district        date  price
4   bj       hd  2019-03-01    7.0
5   bj       hd  2019-04-01    NaN
```

Another test:

```
df.groupby(['city','district']).filter(lambda x: (x['price'].isnull() & x['date']).any())
```

Out:

```
  city district        date  price
0   bj       cy  2019-03-01    NaN
1   bj       cy  2019-04-01    6.0
4   bj       hd  2019-03-01    7.0
5   bj       hd  2019-04-01    NaN
```

But I need is as below. How could I modify the code above? Thanks a lot.

```
  city district      date  price
0   bj       cy  2019/3/1    NaN
1   bj       cy  2019/4/1    6.0
2   sh       hp  2019/3/1    4.0
3   sh       hp  2019/4/1    3.0
```

Comment: In your desired output, I don't understand why rows 2 and 3 should be there. Didn't you say you want to filter for `price is NaN` (at least once per group, I suppose)?

Comment: It needs to `date` is `2019-04-01` and `price` is `NaN`.

Comment: But for the group defined by `sh, hp`, `price` is `4.0` and `3.0`, never `NaN`, so why is this group not filtered out?

Comment: If we put in another way, I want to drop the groups of rows for `date` is `2019-04-01` and its `price` is `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. So jezrael's answer is spot on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need invert mask - here `&` to `|`, `isnull` to `notna`, `eq` to `ne` and `any` to `all`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

f = lambda x: (x['price'].notna() | x['date'].ne('2019-04-01')).all()
df = df.groupby(['city','district']).filter(f)
print (df)
  city district       date  price
0   bj       cy 2019-03-01    NaN
1   bj       cy 2019-04-01    6.0
2   sh       hp 2019-03-01    4.0
3   sh       hp 2019-04-01    3.0
```

Or is possible use `not` for invert boolean `True` to `False` and `False` to `True`:

```
f = lambda x: not (x['price'].isnull() & x['date'].eq('2019-04-01')).any()
df = df.groupby(['city','district']).filter(f)
```

Comment: It works with test data, but with real data, it only filter all rows `date` is `2019-04-01`, i'm confused.

Comment: @ahbon - My solution drop groups with `df[df['price'].isnull() & df['date'].eq('2019-04-01')]` rows, if exist at least one. Not sure if need it.

Comment: I hope to drop the groups of rows for `date` is `2019-04-01` and its `price` is `NaN`.

Comment: @ahbon - For test is possible use `df[df['price'].isnull() & df['date'].eq('2019-04-01')].drop_duplicates('date')` for groups which are removed (by `'city','district'` columns)

Comment: I think maybe the problem is come from there are some `NaN`s from columns used to groupby, such as `city` or `district`?

Comment: @ahbon - if there are NaNs then groups are removed. I try test it.

Comment: @ahbon - Is possible test like `df = df.assign(city = lambda x: x['city'].fillna(-1),district = lambda x: x['district'].fillna(-1)).groupby(['city','district']).filter(f)`, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429491/groupby-columns-with-nan-missing-values) ?